# Error when trying to map a network drive on VMWare Workstation

Tags: networking, mount, vmware

So I am trying to connect to a network drive that has data that I need. I followed the tutorial [here](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2014/08/map-network-drive-onto-ubuntu-14-04/).

I created a directory in the media directory called Z, then I installed the cifs-utils package, with the command

```
sudo apt-get install cifs-utils
```

After this I edited the /etc/nsswitch.conf file, to look like this (added the **wins**):

```
# /etc/nsswitch.conf
#
# Example configuration of GNU Name Service Switch functionality.
# If you have the `glibc-doc-reference' and `info' packages installed, try:
# `info libc "Name Service Switch"' for information about this file.

passwd:         ******
group:          compat
shadow:         compat
gshadow:        files

hosts:          files mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] wins dns
networks:       files

protocols:      db files
services:       db files
ethers:         db files
rpc:            db files

netgroup:       nis
```

after this, I ran the command below to install a package.

```
sudo apt-get install libnss-winbind winbind
```

I made a backup of the /etc/fstab file, then entered the credentials to the drive in the form:

```
username=***
password=***
```

I then created a file that looks like this:

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=5cf6df9a-462a-42bb-aa94-2b29475d6578 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# swap was on /dev/sda5 during installation
UUID=f546dc20-4811-4f03-8296-fe9c9b549197 none            swap    sw              0       0
## Mount Windows (Z)
//IP_ADDRESS /media/Z cifs credentials=/home/my_username/.smbcredentials,iocharset=utf8,gid=1000,uid=1000,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777 0 0
```

The problem is, when I now run:

```
sudo mount -a
```

I get this error:

```
mount error(22): Invalid argument
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs)
```

I'm thinking that maybe this example is deprecated, could anyone help me see where I went wrong?

Comment: What do you get when you with this command: `sudo umount /media/Z` ?

Comment: I get this: `umount: /media/Z: not mounted` @L.D.James